# C# How to override the background image of the foreground image in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i override the list of items picturebox to cashier picturebox. I tried so many things like bringtofront, transparency but nothing works. I hope someone would be able to help me.

[image]
This image shows how i try to combine these two pictureboxes and the result is that.[image]
Here is the image what i want to do or to be my output

Comment: It might be that it's not possible. Use 3 picture boxes instead: 1 for cashier, 1 for the overlapping part and 1 for list of items. The middle one just does nothing but look nice. -- Or use WPF

Comment: Yeah designing like this in wpf is very easy because of XML, but i didn't know anything about using it. i just read some articles about WPF

Comment: Great ! I just tried it and it work . Thank you